# How can i set current time and date as cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I want to set visitors first visiting time and date of my website as cookie.

I tried the code below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var dt = new Date();
   var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
   Cookies.set('vtime', time, { expires: 7, path: '' });
   alert(Cookies.get('vtime')); 
</script>
```

Using the above code the time is changing on reload.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Whenever page refreshes, javascript will be executed so you should use localstorage or session storage if user visiting has any valid session then do it from server end

Comment: you should read the cookie before setting its contents, i.e. if cookie is not set, then set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is cookie gets replaced on every refresh. So just check if the cookie is set already

```
if(!Cookies.get('vtime')) {
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    Cookies.set('vtime', time, { expires: 7, path: '' });
    alert(Cookies.get('vtime')); 
}
```

Comment: No problem @InsightCoders , always glad to help

Comment: One problem, when i close the browser window and reopen the page it reset the time again. I want to keep the time same.